# Installing Kali Linux dual boot Windows 8

Tags: kali-linux, grub2

I have Windows 8 currently installed on my computer I created a 350gb partition. I removed secure boot and enabled legacy boot sources, I booted into a live environment, installed Kali, everything went smooth and flawless, it prompted me that the next time I reboot it will show the Grub boot loader so I reboot and it doesn't show the boot loader. Is there something I did wrong? I asked someone what they thought and he said I didn't install grub on the MBR, I installed it on the partition itself, but I followed the tutorial on this link http://docs.kali.org/installation/dual-boot-kali-with-windows

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the boot loader is not installed properly during Kali Linux installation. Download the boot loader (i.e. grub-pc) from a network mirror in Kali.

Now, boot Kali from a live boot CD/Flash Drive, then run the following commands:

1. In Terminal, type:  sudo fdisk -l

The partition which has Linux under System column is your drive in which Ubuntu Linux is installed. For example, Ubuntu partition drive is '/dev/sda11'

2. Type:  sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
3. Mount the virtual filesystems:

   ```
     sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
     sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc 
     sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   ```
4. Type:  sudo mount --bind /usr/ /mnt/usr    and    sudo chroot /mnt
5. If there is no '/boot/grub/grub.cfg' or it's not correct, create one using              commands:   update-grub    or    update-grub2
6. Now reinstall by typing:    grub-install /dev/sdX
7. Type:    sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX    to verify the installation.
8. Now press Ctrl+D to exit chrooted environment.
9. Unmount the mounted file systems:
     sudo umount /mnt/dev
     sudo umount /mnt/proc
     sudo umount /mnt/sys
10. Reboot the system

After reboot, you should be able to see the grub boot loader.

-Cheers